# Error while passing an action() per component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following button component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: ` <ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="action()">
                {{title}}
              </ion-button>`
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public title: string;
  @Input() public color = 'primary';
  @Input() public action = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

but when I pass the `action()` to it does not work, does anyone know what I need to do to be able to pass this property as a component?

Comment: Can't you rename it with another name because i can see there is an action() function already in the ButtonComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the action function from your parent component you should use @Output() instead of @Input() like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: ` <ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="action.emit(null)">
                {{title}}
              </ion-button>`
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public title: string;
  @Input() public color = 'primary';
  @Output() public action: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and now in your parent component you can call what function you want like this:

```
<app-button (action)="yourFunction($event)"></app-button>
```

try this, if any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`(click)="action()"` means it is expecting a method named `action`, you need to modify a little,

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejwvg7?embed=1&file=src/app/button-component/button-component.component.ts)**

Parent:

```
title = 'Btn Title';
action = "save"

<app-button [title]="title" [action]="action"></app-button>
```

Child:

```
<ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="this[action]()">
   {{title}}
</ion-button>
```

or,

```
<ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="onClick()">
            {{title}}
</ion-button>


onClick() {
   this[this.action]()
}
```

Comment: I come across this error when I pass the property this[this.action] is not a function

HTML: <app-button title="Buscar" action="go()"></app-button>

Comment: TS: 
  public go(): void {
    console.log('test')
  }

Comment: See app.component.ts.

Comment: I wanted to execute the method that comes from app.component.ts

Comment: ` [action]="action"`, here you are passing from parent only